# Linq-To-Entities using method to select new object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I try to use the same select query multiple times in my application.
For example I have this select statement:

```
 _db.tbl_itembundlecontents
                    .Select(z => new SingleItemDTO
                    {
                        amount = z.amount,
                        id = z.id,
                        position = z.position,
                        contentType = new BasicMaterialDTO
                        {
                            id = z.tbl_items.id,
                            img = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.img,
                            name = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.name,
                            namekey = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.namekey,
                            info = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.info,
                            weight = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.weight
                        }
                    });
```

but i also have this:

```
 _db.tbl_itembundle
                .Where(x => x.type == 2)
                .Select(y => new ItemBundleDTO
                {
                    name = y.name,
                    namekey = y.namekey.
                    contents = y.tbl_itembundlecontents
                    .Select(z => new SingleItemDTO
                    {
                        amount = z.amount,
                        id = z.id,
                        position = z.position,
                        contentType = new BasicMaterialDTO
                        {
                            id = z.tbl_items.id,
                            img = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.img,
                            name = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.name,
                            namekey = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.namekey,
                            info = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.info,
                            weight = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.weight
                        }
                    })
                });
```

As you can see I use exactly the same code (for the SingleItemDTO) in both linq select statements. Is there a way to separate the code of my first select statement (without getting the NotSupportedException) and reuse it again? My second query should look like this:

```
_db.tbl_itembundle
                .Where(x => x.type == 2)
                .Select(y => new ItemBundleDTO
                {
                    name = y.name,
                    namekey = y.namekey.
                    contents = y.tbl_itembundlecontents.ToDTO()
                });
```

Answer (score 8):

It's possible, but in a bit unusual way.

Create a helper method and move the **selector** part of your first query like this

```
static Expression<Func<[tbl_itembundlecontents entity type], SingleItemDTO>> ToSingleItemDTO()
{
    return z => new SingleItemDTO
    {
        amount = z.amount,
        id = z.id,
        position = z.position,
        contentType = new BasicMaterialDTO
        {
            id = z.tbl_items.id,
            img = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.img,
            name = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.name,
            namekey = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.namekey,
            info = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.info,
            weight = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.weight
        }
    };
}
```

Now the first query can be like this

```
_db.tbl_itembundlecontents.Select(ToSingleItemDTO());
```

and the second like this

```
_db.tbl_itembundle
    .Where(x => x.type == 2)
    .Select(y => new ItemBundleDTO
    {
        name = y.name,
        namekey = y.namekey.
        contents = y.tbl_itembundlecontents.AsQueryable().Select(ToSingleItemDTO())
    });
```

Note the `AsQueryable()` after the navigation property, this is the esential part to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
public static class HelperExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<SingleItemDTO> ToDto(this IEnumerable<Tbl_itembundlecontents> items)
    {
        return items.Select(z => z.ToDto());
    }

    public static SingleItemDTO ToDto(this Tbl_itembundlecontents z)
    {
        return new SingleItemDTO
        {
            amount = z.amount,
            id = z.id,
            position = z.position,
            contentType = new BasicMaterialDTO
            {
                id = z.tbl_items.id,
                img = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.img,
                name = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.name,
                namekey = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.namekey,
                info = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.info,
                weight = z.tbl_items.tbl_material.weight
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This will throw the same exception

Comment: Ah sorry, yeah it's the linq to sql conversion that raising the exception, I know it's a little cheating but you could to 
    .Where(x => x.type == 2).ToList() 
and then do the projection

Comment: Yes, calling `ToList()` would probably be the easiest. Yet, that would mean the generated SQL `SELECT` may contain unnecessary fields and further Navigation Properties access (during mapping) would invoke extra queries (using Lazy Load mechanism).

Comment: As @haim770 already mentioned I don't want to `SELECT` unnecessary fields. But [LinqKit](http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2013/07/17/i-don-39-t-always-re-use-my-linq-to-ef-but-when-i-do-i-prefer-linqkit.aspx) is probably the extension I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

or something like this?

```
public object[] BicagiKullanabilenMakinalar { get; set; }

item.BicagiKullanabilenMakinalar = await (from bicak in _dbContext.BicakMakinas
                                      join islem in _dbContext.Islems on bicak.Islemkod equals islem.Islemkod into islemInto
                                      from islem in islemInto.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      join makina in _dbContext.MakinaKarts on bicak.Makinakodu equals makina.Makinakodu into makinaInto
                                      from makina in makinaInto.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      where islem.Islemtipkod == "002"
                                      && bicak.Bicakkodu == bicakKodu
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          MakinaKodu = bicak.Makinakodu,
                                          MakinaAdi = makina.Makinaadi,
                                          KodAciklama = islem.Kodaciklama
                                      })
                                      .Distinct()
                                      .OrderBy(e => e.MakinaAdi)
                                      .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Response;

```
   "bicagiKullanabilenMakinalar": [
        {
            "makinaKodu": "003",
            "makinaAdi": "GALLUS R200B",
            "kodAciklama": "BIÇAKLAMA (TAHTA DISLI)"
        },
        {
            "makinaKodu": "004",
            "makinaAdi": "ZONTEN",
            "kodAciklama": "BIÇAKLAMA (TAHTA DISLI)"
        }
    ],
```