# Reusing queries with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to make some queries using EF-Core and I have the following code

```
public List<Visitation> GetAllVisitations()
    {
        return this.hospital.Visitations
            .Where(v => v.DoctorId == this.Doctor.Id)
            .Select(v => new Visitation
            {
                Doctor = v.Doctor,
                Patient = v.Patient,
                Date = v.Date,
                Comments = v.Comments
            })
            .ToList();
    }

public List<Visitation> GetVisitationByPatient(int id)
    {
        var patient = this.GetPatientById(id);

        return this.hospital.Visitations
            .Where(v => v.PatientId == patient.Id)
            .Select(v => new Visitation
            {
                Doctor = v.Doctor,
                Patient = v.Patient,
                Date = v.Date,
                Comments = v.Comments
            })
            .ToList();
    }
```

It is pretty obvious that the Select statement is the same in both methods. However I know that EF Core uses Expression<Func>, rather than Func therefore I do not know how to make an Expression, which can be used in both Select statements.

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607575/linq-to-entities-using-method-to-select-new-object/33607748

Comment: What type is `hospital`? Also, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

The query won't execute until you call `.ToList()`. So you may take the partial query up to the `.Where()` and pass it to a function that adds the `Select()` portion.

Something like this:

```
public List<Visitation> GetAllVisitations()
    {
        var query = this.hospital.Visitations
            .Where(v => v.DoctorId == this.Doctor.Id);
            
        return this.addTransformation(query)
                   .ToList();
    }

public List<Visitation> GetVisitationByPatient(int id)
    {
        var patient = this.GetPatientById(id);

        var query = this.hospital.Visitations
                        .Where(v => v.PatientId == patient.Id)
            
        return this.addTransformation(query)
                   .ToList();
    }

public IQueriable<Visitation> AddTransformation(IQueriable<Visitation> query)
{
     return query.Select(v => new Visitation
                {
                    Doctor = v.Doctor,
                    Patient = v.Patient,
                    Date = v.Date,
                    Comments = v.Comments
                });
}
```